# moving Image View from point to another

Tags: java, android, animation, imageview

I would like to move an image view from one point to another when a particular button is clicked.

Here's my code:

```
int e = 0 ;  
Button d = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
d.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TranslateAnimation move = new TranslateAnimation(e, e + 1, e, e + 1);
        move.setDuration(1000);
        move.setFillAfter(true);
        image.startAnimation(move);
    }  
});
```

But when I clicked the button nothing happened! 
How do I make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation probably works but it will only move the view by one pixel, which is not that noticeable. Try changing the values of your translate animation.